# XML Node accessing attribute with namespace

Tags: php, xml

This is my xml data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns1:catalog
xmlns:ns1="http://www.omnichannelintegrationlayer.com/xml/catalog/2016-01-01" catalog-id="at-master-catalog">
<ns1:product product-id="4132002004">
    <ns1:min-order-quantity>1</ns1:min-order-quantity>
    <ns1:step-quantity>1</ns1:step-quantity>
    <ns1:short-description
        xmlns:ns2="xml" ns2:lang="de-AT">Jogginghose Cacy jr
    </ns1:short-description>
    <ns1:short-description
        xmlns:ns2="xml" ns2:lang="de-CH">Jogginghose Cacy jr
    </ns1:short-description>
</ns1:product>
```

I'm trying to filter the xml the short-description base on ns2:lang attribute.

This is what I've done so far:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("//ns1:product[@product-id='".$productid."']/ns1:short-description/") as $short_description) {
 $namespaces = $short_description->getNameSpaces(true);
    $ns1        = $short_description->children($namespaces['ns1']);
    $ns2        = $short_description->children($namespaces['ns2']);

    var_dump($ns2);
    echo $ns2["lang"];
}
```

The output of var_dump looks okay:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#27 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(5) "de-AT" } }
```

But I can't access the array because when I echo $ns2["lang"], I'm getting NULL.

I already tried different solution like declaring namespace first but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the complete code?

Comment: haven't you tried `->attributes()`?

Comment: When I try attributes() I'm getting, Warning: var_dump(): Node no longer exists

Comment: @ChetanAmeta this is the whole code so far

Comment: @rapidoodle what does `$xml` have?

Comment: Your XML doesn't have any tags named `short-description` - what are you expecting your xpath expression to match?

Comment: @iainn sorry I corrected the node name. it's should be short-description

Comment: Your value is in the attributes. Based on the var_dump, try it like this: `var_dump($ns2->attributes()->lang);`

Comment: I already try it @Thefourthbird and I'm getting NULL too

Comment: @ChetanAmeta 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

Comment: i think some issue with PHP itself.. can not use attribute function its giving warning.. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75168

Comment: Is it possible to just ignore the namespaces in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you are looking for are in the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) and the attributes use a namespace which you can pass as a parameter to the  attributes method.

The attribute itself is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and has a method [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) to get the text content that is directly in this element.

You could for example use `echo $short_description->attributes($namespaces['ns2'])->lang;` or cast it to a `(string)`

You might update your code to:

```
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
foreach ($xml->xpath("//ns1:product[@product-id='".$productid."']/ns1:short-description") as $short_description) {
    $langAsString = (string)$short_description->attributes($namespaces['ns2'])->lang;
    echo $langAsString . "<br>";
}
```

That would give you:

```
de-AT
de-CH
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DbTus)

Comment: You didn't know how much help you did dude.. Thank you so much.